# Regular expression to remove part of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am kinda new to regex, I have a string e.g

```
String test = @"c:\test\testing";
```

Now what I would like to accomplish is to removing all words up to "\".  So in this case the work being removed is "testing".  Howerver, this word may be different everytime.
So bascally remove everyting until the first \ is found.

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean first "\" from right to left?

Comment: Regex is not the only solution. I prefer a more readable solution.

Comment: Your wording is a little vague.  Are you looking for the first or last '\'?  You say first, but your example indicates last.

Comment: Depends on how you look at it.  E.g String test = "c:\test\testing

I want to look like "C:\test\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean remove backwards, until the first \ is found?

You could easily do this without regexes:

```
var lastIndex = myString.LastIndexOf('\\');
if (lastIndex != -1)
{
    myString = myString.Substring(0, lastIndex + 1); // keep the '\\' you found
}
```

But if you're really just trying to get the directory component of a path, you can use this:

```
var directoryOfPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
```

Although IIRC that method call will strip the trailing backslash.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex pattern:

```
(?!\\)([^\\]*)$
```

Do a replace on this pattern with the empty string, as shown below:

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?!\\)([^\\]*)$");

var result = re.Replace(@"c:\test\testing", string.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

However, consider using the System.IO namespace, specifically the Path class, instead of Regex.

Comment: WHAT IS STRING.EMPTY ?

Comment: @DemonAppProgrammer It is a static field available on the built-in String class that contains an empty string value. In C# it can be referenced via the expression `string.Empty` because `string` is a C# keyword for that string class. [Here is the documentation for that field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`\\\w+$` and replace it with `\`

Or you can use the following approach

`(?<=\\)\w+$` In this case you just replace the match with an empty string.

Comment: `(?<=\\)\w+(?=\\)?` This pattern is to find yout all path parameters. i.e. it will match as follows c:\ `test` \ `testing`

Answer (score 1):

`regex.replace(str,"^.*?\\","");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without regex:

```
String test = @"c:\test\testing";
int lastIndex = test.LastIndexOf("\");
test = test.Remove(0, lastIndex >= 0 ? lastIndex : 0);
```

Comment: Just one note, `string.Remove` doesn't (of course) modify the original string, so you'd still need to assign the return value.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx) for this, or even a substring action.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test\testing");
String dirName = dir.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "remove" or manipulate file paths, you can skip the basic `Regex` class altogether and use the class `Path` from `System.IO`. This class will give you suitable methods for all you needs in changing/extracting file names.