# Remove part of a string between an start and end

Tags: c#, string

Code first:

```
   string myString = "<at>onePossibleName</at> some question here regarding <at>disPossibleName</at>"
    // some code to handle myString and save it in myEditedString
    Console.WriteLine(myEditedString);
    //output now is: some question here regarding <at>disPossibleName</at>
```

I want to remove `<at>onePossibleName</at>` from myString. The string `onePossibleName` and `disPossbileName` could be any other string.

So far I am working with

```
string myEditedString = string.Join(" ", myString.Split(' ').Skip(1));
```

The problem here would be that if `onePossibleName` becomes `one Possible Name`.

Same goes for the try with `myString.Remove(startIndex, count)` - this is not the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098668/regular-expression-to-remove-part-of-a-string)

Comment: This is a bit unclear. It could be any string? Then how do you know what string you are trying to remove? Is it always inside of the `<at>` tags? There isn't enough detail here.

Comment: use a regex to remove the string between <at></at>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be different method depending on what you want, you can go with a IndexOf and a SubString, regex would be a solution too.

```
// SubString and IndexOf method
// Usefull if you don't care of the word in the at tag, and you want to remove the first at tag
if (myString.Contains("</at>"))
{
    var myEditedString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("</at>") + 5);
}
```

```
// Regex method
var stringToRemove = "onePossibleName";
var rgx = new Regex($"<at>{stringToRemove}</at>");
var myEditedString = rgx.Replace(myString, string.Empty, 1); // The 1 precise that only the first occurrence will be replaced
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this generic regular expression.

```
var myString = "<at>onePossibleName</at> some question here regarding <at>disPossibleName</at>";
var rg = new Regex(@"<at>(.*?)<\/at>");
var result = rg.Replace(myString, "").Trim();
```

This would remove all 'at' tags and the content between. The `Trim()` call is to remove any white space at the beginning/end of the string after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "<at>onePossibleName</at> some question here regarding <at>disPossibleName</at>"

int sFrom = myString.IndexOf("<at>") + "<at>".Length;
int sTo = myString.IndexOf("</at>");

string myEditedString = myString.SubString(sFrom, sFrom - sTo);
Console.WriteLine(myEditedString);
//output now is: some question here regarding <at>disPossibleName</at>
```